# failed to install TensorFlow Lite using ck framework

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have found a program to classify images using TensorFlow Lite at http://cknowledge.org/shared-programs.html#image-classification-tflite. I was following provided README but got stuck when I was installing lib-tflite-1.7.0-src-static package for android23 - ck framework did not find my android ndk:

```
plam@mrk-23:~$ ck install package:lib-tflite-1.7.0-src-static --target_os=android23-arm64

  -----------------------------------
  Resolving software dependencies ...

*** Dependency 1 = compiler (C++ compiler):

 ********
 WARNING: no registered CK environment was found for "C++ compiler" dependency with tags="compiler,lang-cpp" and setup={"target_os_bits": "64", "host_os_uoa": "linux-64", "target_os_uoa": "android23-arm64"}

  Trying to automatically detect required software ...

  1) Checking if "Android NDK GCC compiler" (compiler.gcc.android.ndk / bfc4274b1d8f83bb) is installed ...

  Searching for Android NDK GCC compiler (ndk-build) to automatically register in the CK - it may take some time, please wait ...

    * Searching in /usr ...
    * Searching in /opt ...
    * Searching in /home/plam ...

  Search completed in 2.1 secs. Found 0 target files (may be pruned) ...
  (warning during intermediate step: software was not automatically found on your system! Please, install it and re-try again!)

  2) Checking if "Android NDK LLVM compiler" (compiler.llvm.android.ndk / 47b0a9cd88368dc6) is installed ...

  -----------------------------------
  Resolving software dependencies ...

*** Dependency 1 = ndk-gcc (Android NDK GCC):

 ********
 WARNING: no registered CK environment was found for "Android NDK GCC" dependency with tags="compiler,gcc,ndk" and setup={"target_os_bits": "64", "host_os_uoa": "linux-64", "target_os_uoa": "android23-arm64"}

  Trying to automatically detect required software ...

  1) Checking if "Android NDK GCC compiler" (compiler.gcc.android.ndk / bfc4274b1d8f83bb) is installed ...

  Searching for Android NDK GCC compiler (ndk-build) to automatically register in the CK - it may take some time, please wait ...

    * Searching in /usr ...
    * Searching in /opt ...
    * Searching in /home/plam ...

  Search completed in 2.1 secs. Found 0 target files (may be pruned) ...
  (warning during intermediate step: software was not automatically found on your system! Please, install it and re-try again!)
    No software auto-detection scripts found for this software in CK :( ...

       Checked following related CK soft entries:
        * compiler.gcc.android.ndk

  Searching and installing CK software packages ...
    * tags:        compiler,gcc,ndk
    * or tags:
    * no tags:

    CK packages are not found for this software :( !

****** Installation notes: ******
You can download and install Native Android NDK for your platform from
* http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

You can also download CrystaX NDK (extra libs and improved C++ support) from
* https://www.crystax.net/en/download


*********************************
       Would you like to manually register software, i.e. if it is in an unusual path (y/N):

  (warning during intermediate step: no registered CK environment was found for "Android NDK GCC" dependency with tags="compiler,gcc,ndk" and setup={"target_os_bits": "64", "host_os_uoa": "linux-64", "target_os_uoa": "android23-arm64"})
    No software auto-detection scripts found for this software in CK :( ...

       Checked following related CK soft entries:
        * compiler.gcc.milepost
        * compiler.icc
        * compiler.ctuning-cc
        * compiler.microsoft
        * compiler.open64
        * compiler.gcc
        * compiler.gcc.android.ndk
        * compiler.llvm
        * compiler.llvm.android.ndk
        * compiler.pgi

  Searching and installing CK software packages ...
    * tags:        compiler,lang-cpp
    * or tags:
    * no tags:

    CK packages are not found for this software :( !

       Would you like to open wiki pages about related software (with possible installation info) (y/N):

CK error: [package] no registered CK environment was found for "C++ compiler" dependency with tags="compiler,lang-cpp" and setup={"target_os_bits": "64", "host_os_uoa": "linux-64", "target_os_uoa": "android23-arm64"}!
```

I think that it is because android ndk is installed in a not usual place on our cluster: /misc/android-ndk-r17b

Does anyone know how to tell this ck framework to detect my android ndk in not standard place? I use Ubuntu 18.04 and installed ck from their GitHub from https://github.com/ctuning/ck.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must first help CK to detect your GCC from Android NDK in a ununsal path as follows:

```
$ ck detect soft:compiler.gcc.android.ndk --target_os=android23-arm64 --search_dirs=<<INSTALLATION PATH OF ANDROID NDK>>
```

You can then check that CK registered your Android NDK as a virtual environment as follows:

```
$ ck show env --target_os=android23-arm64
$ ck virtual env --tags=android,ndk,gcc --target_os=android23-arm64
```

You should now be able to restart installation of TensorFlow as follows:

```
$ ck install package:lib-tflite-1.7.0-src-static --target_os=android23-arm64
$ ck compile program:image-classification-tflite --target_os=android23-arm64 --speed
$ ck run program:image-classification-tflite --target_os=android23-arm64
```

You can also detect Clang from Android NDK in a similar way as follows:

```
$ ck detect soft:compiler.llvm.android.ndk --target_os=android23-arm64 --search_dirs=<<INSTALLATION PATH OF ANDROID NDK>>
```

But I am not sure if it will work with above tflite package - you can try though...

If you need, you can find other software which can be detected by CK here: http://cKnowledge.org/shared-soft-detection-plugins.html

By the way, I would suggest to ask such questions in the CK mailing list or Slack channel - you may get help a bit faster: https://github.com/ctuning/ck/wiki/Contacts

Comment: gfursin, I thank you for this detailed answer, it worked for me.